# Assign result of calculation in sympy to function

Tags: python, fft, sympy

I looked through several questions here on SO, but I could not find a solution for this problem:
I calculate a fourier transformation in sympy with `fourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)`. I assigned `tau`, `t` and `w` with `tau, t, w = symbols('tau t w')`. How can I put the result of the FT into a function, e.g. something like

```
g(tau, w) = fourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)
```

? When I write it like that, I get the error `can't assign to function call`. When I do it like

```
g = fourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)
```

then I can not call it (as usually) with `g(tau, w)` or something similar. Is there a way to do that?
Edit: What I want to have as a final result is:

```
g(tau, w) = 2*tau/(tau**2 + 4*pi**2*w**2)
```

and I can call `g` simply with (f.eks) `g(2, 3)`.
Edit II: Python call:

```
>>> fourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)
2*tau/(tau**2 + 4*pi**2*w**2)
```

Comment: What are tau and w parameters referencing to?

Comment: how are you going to assing a value to the result of a function?

Comment: How do you want to put the result into a function?

Comment: @lapinkoira: `tau` and `w` are two parameters for the function, `w` is the frequency, `tau` a free parameter.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde: I want to use the result of the FT as a new function, question updated.

Comment: Ok I have no idea what fourier_transform is. Does it return a function or a tuple?

Comment: It returns `2*tau/(tau**2 + 4*pi**2*w**2)`

Comment: So it returns a number, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it returns a function, depending on `tau` and `w`.

Comment: what is the t variable?

Comment: Please also consider checking my answer, which is quite practical too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if you want an inline solution, you can use lambda to approach so:

```
g = lambda tau,w: ourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)
```

Assuming the `t` is a local variable.

By the way, you can also use the standard function definition, but **never** try to define a function as a variable.

Comment: Yep, something like that is what I was looking for!

Comment: @arc_lupus consider accepting my answer if it is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

So you create your g method and use the fourier_transform inside the g method like this:

But you have to provide the t also

```
def g(tau, w):
    return fourier_transform(exp(-tau*abs(t)), t, w)
```

Comment: `t` is the variable in the time-regime, while `w` is the function variable in the space regime.

Comment: You mean w is a method?

Comment: @lapinkoira: Have you already heard of the fourier transformation? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)? There everything is explained (`w` is a variable, not a method)

Comment: Yeah the problem is the way you are explaining yourself is so confusing nobody here didnt know at the begging you just wanted a simple method definition which you could have found with less than 5 minutes using google. We dont need to know t is a time-regime variable or w is a space regime variable, that's confusing, they both are just variables you have to define and I didnt see your t definition in your code yet.